# Shell command for all files in a folder (macOs)

Tags: macos, shell, terminal

I am using the following command on the terminal in order to ungray files on a hard drive:

```
SetFile -c "" -t "" path/to/file
```

However, there are a few folders that have many files and I would know if it is possible to use this command recursively on the terminal so it works with all of them with the same command.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the `find` command with its `-exec` option? It can be used for executing a command on all (specified) documents found in a given directory:

```
find path/to/file -exec SetFile -c "" -t "" {} "+"
```

The `{}` will be replaced by the results (filenames) returned by `find` in the execution of `SetFile`, and `"+"` is used to tell `find` that all the results will be given to `SetFile` at once. (Alternatively, replacing `"+"` with `";"` will give one filename to `SetFile` at a time, and execute `SetFile` as many times as the number of results returned by `find`.)

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks